# SMTP error using bridge instead of NAT on virtualbox with python

Tags: python, smtp, virtualbox, nat, bridge

I am trying to send a simple mail using python with the smtplib on a virtual machine (host: win10, guest:kde).

When the virtual maschine uses a bridged network I get the following error on the following line:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.de', 587)


    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 306, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

When changing the network adapter back to NAT I receive no errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the DNS configuration of your guest machine? It looks like your guest cannot reach a DNS server.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @EvensF. I changed the DNS config as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/641933/how-to-get-virtualbox-vms-to-use-hosts-dns) and now it seems to work.